# getting error "could not start command pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex"

Tags: pdftex

I  use a texmakerwin_32

```
 \documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{amsfonts}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \begin{document}
 sharath
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Did you actually install latex as well? A missing latex installation is usually the cause of this problem, which a search on "could not start comnand" would have told you. Remember that in the world of latex, latex the interpreter and the chosen editor basically have nothing to do with each other. You are free to use any editor as long at it saves stuff as text.

Comment: @daleif yeah latex is also installed

Comment: Then which latex? And can you run latex from a terminal/command line?